# Open connection to mysql DB in the rake task

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have a Rails 3.2 app which use PostgreSQL to store all the information.

But in one Rake task I need to make a connection with the MySQL server. I tried to do this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter  => "mysql2",
    :database => "foo",
    :user => "root", 
    :password => "",
)
```

But it just replace my default PostgreSQL connection with this temporary MySQL.

How to make the additional connection for the instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a very simple solution: to the the vanila mysql2 gem (https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2)

Now my code looks like:

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :database => "foobar", :password => "")
users = client.query("SELECT * FROM users")
```

After that I have an array of results.

Comment: Is there a postgres version of this method? gem activerecord-postgresql-adapter (0.0.1)

Answer (score 2):

Don't establish it on ActiveRecord::Base.

establish_connection connects to a database from a class, as you've discovered, so when you do it on AR:Base, every subclass of that (to whit, the entire database) has the connection established on it, replacing the current one.

Basically, you create a class for each of the tables you want to connect to, and call the establish connection method in those. If you want to do it in several tables, then create a module with it in and include it.

```
class MyCustomClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(
   :adapter  => "mysql2",
   :database => "foo",
   :user => "root", 
   :password => "",
  )
end

MyCustomClass.find(1)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't need models at all. Just connect to the mysql and run queries

Comment: What exactly are you trying to retrieve? If you've got the class with the connection in it (as you do in my example), and you really just want to run a single query, you can always do MyCustomClass.connection.execute("sql goes here")?

Comment: I am trying to convert a plain mysql table into Rails models